# Changes are lost when document is edited concurrently

Tags: ms-word, webdav, ithit-webdav-server

I've tested the IT Hit WebDAV server implementation on the https://www.ajaxbrowser.com/ and found a strange behavior with document locking.

If the same document will be opened by two users, it will be locked by the first and the second will get a warning window. You can choose the option in the window to save the document using a merge tool, and when the first user completes their edit, the second user will overwrite the changes which were made by the first user.

You can use this test case to check this behavior:

1. User1 opens a document
2. User1 clicks on Enable editing
3. User2 opens the document
4. User2 gets a warning window and select the option with using a merge tool
5. User1 and User2 makes some changes in the document.
6. User2 tries to save the document and gets a warning about document lock status. "Document is locked by another user" or something like that.
7. User1 completes their edit, clicks on save button and closes their MS Word.
8. User2 can save the document since now or they can wait for a message from Word about the document lock status update.
9. User2 clicks on save and word saves the document without any merge tool appearing. This action overwrites all changes, which were made by User1.

Additional info about users:

- User1: OS Windows10, Word 2016 MSO (16.0.4498.1000) 64-bit
  = User2: OS Windows7, Word 2016 MSO (16.0.4266.1001) 32-bit

How can I fix this problem? Is it common problem or it relates only to my local environment?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in [IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine for .NET v6 Beta](https://www.webdavsystem.com/server/download). It supports MS Office merging and proper 'If-modified-since' and 'If' with ETag headers processing.